# jquery after() showing [object Object] instead of the object HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV I'm attempting to move to a different location in the DOM when the page loads. I'd like it not show up in both locations, just in the new one.

I'm using :

```
j$('#bodyCell').after('<td>'+j$('#toolbar')+'</td>');
```

However, the page is displaying [Object object] in the TD. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you're appending an object. What is `#toolbar`?

Comment: `j$('#toolbar')` doesn't return a string.  It returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

```
j$('#bodyCell').after('<td>'+j$('#toolbar').get(0).outerHTML+'</td>');
```