# append dynamic element .find() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj[0].items.length; i++) {
    //var html3 ;
    html3 = '<li><span>' + obj[0].items[i].local + '</span></li>';
    //$("#thelist").append('<li><span>'+html3+'</span></li>');
    for (var a = 0; a < getObjectLength(obj[0].items[i]); a++) {
        if (typeof (obj[0]['items'][i]['item' + a]) !== typeof (undefined)) {
            //html2 += obj[0]['items'][i]['item'+a];
            console.log()
            //$($.parseHTML(html3)).find($.parseHTML(html3)).insertBefore('sa');
            html3 += $($.parseHTML(html3)).find("span").end().append(obj[0]['items'][i]['item' + a])
            // $("#thelist li").insertBefore(html2);
            console.log(html3);
        }

    }
    $("#thelist").append(html3);
}
html3 = '';
```

I'm not managing to find the add element after element it shows this is print

```
<li><span>padaria</span></li>[object Object]
```

Comment: a string + an object becomes `string[object Object]`. you need to instead turn the object into a string, or the string into an element and add it to object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery after() showing \[object Object\] instead of the object HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171178/jquery-after-showing-object-object-instead-of-the-object-html)

Comment: What is `.find("span").end()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line add a jquery object in `html3`

```
html3 += $($.parseHTML(html3)).find("span").end().append(obj[0]['items'][i]['item' + a])
```

You can do this instead

```
html3 += $($.parseHTML(html3)).find("span").end().append(obj[0]['items'][i]['item' + a]).html();
```